# Limiting JSON Response in Swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4

This may seem like a noob question but I'm receiving a response from the Wikipedia API and sometimes, depending on what the request is, the response of the image description is way too long. This is what I have for this particular request.

```
let imageDescription = imageJSON["query"]["pages"][pageid]["extract"].stringValue
```

I'd like to limit it to 50 words. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to break the string up into an array of separate words, limit the array to 50 items, and then put the array back together.  You could achieve this like so:

```
var imageDescription = imageJSON["query"]["pages"][pageid]["extract"].stringValue

imageDescription = imageDescription.components(separatedBy: " ").prefix(50).joined(separator: " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not split a string by space or punctuations in hope of getting the words. Some languages (such as Chinese and Japanese) do not separate the words by space. See [this article](https://medium.com/@sorenlind/three-ways-to-enumerate-the-words-in-a-string-using-swift-7da5504f0062) for details.

```
func takeFirst(words wordCount: Int, in str: String) -> String {
    let fullRange = str.startIndex..<str.endIndex
    var count = 0
    var substr: Substring = ""

    str.enumerateSubstrings(in: fullRange, options: .byWords) { _, _, enclosingRange, stop in
        count += 1
        if enclosingRange.upperBound == fullRange.upperBound || count >= wordCount {
            substr = str[str.startIndex..<enclosingRange.upperBound]
            stop = true
        }
    }

    return String(substr)
}

let imageDescription = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed pulvinar semper sapien, sit amet feugiat risus pulvinar a. Sed in aliquam sem. Nullam lacinia sagittis ipsum, et congue lectus pulvinar quis. Vestibulum elementum mattis feugiat. Nam velit elit, facilisis non ipsum vel, ornare aliquam velit. Curabitur hendrerit ante sed odio porttitor, pellentesque molestie sapien eleifend. Etiam porttitor fermentum egestas. Cras dui justo, vulputate non porta sed, congue eu lacus."
let shortImageDescription = takeFirst(words: 5, in: imageDescription)
print(shortImageDescription)
```

Another example in Chinese to illustrate the point:

```
let imageDescription = "今天你好吗?" // first two characters form one word: "today"
                                    // third character is its own word: "you"
                                    // fourth chasracter is its own word: "well"
                                    // fifth character is its own word" "huh"
let shortImageDescription = takeFirst(words: 3, in: imageDescription) // 今天你好
```